# Sopranos: Mergers & Acquisitions - Devil's Advocate Homage?

Tags: reference, the-sopranos, the-devils-advocate

There is a scene in the episode of The Sopranos, called "Mergers and Acquisitions" where Valentina La Paz gets up after being with Tony Sopranos. The positioning of her body with regards to the camera and the way she puts on a top and, in particular, the look on her face seems to be an homage to the scene in Devil's Advocate where the wives are trying on clothes and Mary sees a demonic face on one of the women.

Is there any evidence at all to support that this is deliberate?

I know that homages to Goodfellas throughout the show are deliberate.

Comment: I don't remember the specific episode to which you're referring, so I won't put this as an answer unless requested: it may be a reference to "American Psycho", when Patrick Bateman tells a woman a club that he's into "murders and executions" and she mishears him as "mergers and acquisitions".

Comment: Interesting, I'm sure that is a deep reference. It is however better as a comment since it doesn't really answer the question. Cheers